# Having All solr node in cassandra. DSE4.5

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

My requirment is:

I am getting very high freq of data and need to populate that data into tables and read from solr .

So my question is Can i create all node with Solr in DSE4.5 ?Is there any drawback of it where i have all solr nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only drawback to having all data centers being Solr-enabled is that you have to workload isolation for pure Cassandra queries, but if all/most of your queries are Solr, that's fine.

You might consider having multiple Solr data centers for workload isolation if you have diffeent categories of queries, some that are shorter and faster and others that are more complex and slower.